# FastAPI How to fix error walking file system: OSError [Errno 40] Too many levels of symbolic links: '/sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon0/subsystem?

Tags: python, docker, fastapi, uvicorn

I have FastAPI (Python) with uvicorn[standard]. And I have this error:

```
error walking file system: OSError [Errno 40] Too many levels of symbolic links: '/sys/class/vtconsole/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0/subsystem/vtcon0'
```

If I use just uvicorn, everything is okay, but I need uvicorn[standard]. How to fix it?

I use it in Docker.

Comment: Do you launch it with `--reload` flag? I had the same problem, when I tried to use the `--reload` flag but forgot to set `--reload-dir` path.

Comment: This is my final solution without errors: https://github.com/kosyachniy/web/tree/main/api

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar error.

## error walking file system: FileNotFoundError

I added the `--reload-dir` as suggested by @amoskaliov

Updated my docker-entrypont.sh to:

```
/wait && uvicorn pm.asgi:application --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000  \
--reload \
--reload-dir ./dir1 \
--reload-dir ./dir2 \
--reload-dir ./dir3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN pip install uvicorn -y
RUN pip install uvicorn[standard]
```

Answer (score 0):

when I use  Linux service ,I have met this sitation.
here is my solution:

```
    uvicorn.run(app='main:app', host="0.0.0.0", port=8010, reload=False, reload_dirs=None, debug=False)
```

I turn the parameter debug to false .